# How can I convert three.js JSONLoader to ObjectLoader?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I had multiple files loading and working correctly using the following code for three.js JSONLoader:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rotating Sphere</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <!-- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js -->
    <script src="http://www.amdesigngroup.com/clients/AM_6292_Learning/js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.amdesigngroup.com/clients/AM_6292_Learning/js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <!-- Tween.js: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tween.js/ -->
    <script src="http://www.amdesigngroup.com/clients/AM_6292_Learning/js/Tween.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; background-color:#6cdbf5;">
    <div class="canvas-wrapper">
      <canvas id="mycanvas">

      </canvas>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script>

      function createObject(filePath) {
        // Set up the scene, camera, and renderer as global variables.
        var canvas = null,
            scene = null,
            camera = null,
            renderer = null,
            mesh = null,
            mesh2 = null,
            object = null;

        init();
        run();

        // Sets up the scene.
        function init() {

          // Get canvas
          canvas = document.getElementById( "mycanvas" );

          // Create the scene and set the scene size.
          scene = new THREE.Scene();
          var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
              HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

          // Create a renderer and add it to the DOM.
          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, alpha:true, canvas:canvas});
          renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
          document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

          // Create a camera, zoom it out from the model a bit, and add it to the scene.
          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 20000);
          camera.position.set(0,6,0);
          camera.lookAt(scene.position);
          scene.add(camera);

          // Create an event listener that resizes the renderer with the browser window.
          window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
                HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          });

          // Set the background color of the scene to transparent
          //renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);

          // Create a light, set its position, and add it to the scene.
          var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
          light.position.set(0,0,-100);
          scene.add(light);

          // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
          var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
          loader.load( filePath, function(geometry, materials){
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x55B663});
            mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
            mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
            mesh.rotation.x = - (Math.PI / 2);
            mesh.position.set(-1.5, 0, 0);
            scene.add(mesh);
            object = mesh;
            //animate(mesh);
          });

          // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
          var loader2 = new THREE.JSONLoader();
          loader2.load( "http://www.amdesigngroup.com/clients/AM_6292_Learning/models/ConstructionManA_2/ConstructionManA_2.json", function(geometry, materials){
            var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x55B663});
            mesh2 = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
            mesh2.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
            mesh2.rotation.x = - (Math.PI / 2);
            //mesh2.scale.set(.65, .65, .65);
            mesh2.position.set(1.5, 0, 0);
            scene.add(mesh2);

            //animate(mesh2);
          });

          // Add OrbitControls so that we can pan around with the mouse.
          controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        }
        
        /* rotate mesh */
        function animate(mesh) {
          var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.rotation)
            .to({ z: "-" + Math.PI/2}, 2500) // relative animation
            .onComplete(function() {
                // Check that the full 360 degrees of rotation, 
                // and calculate the remainder of the division to avoid overflow.
                if (Math.abs(mesh.rotation.z)>=2*Math.PI) {
                    mesh.rotation.y = mesh.rotation.z % (2*Math.PI);
                }
            })
            .start();
          tween.repeat(Infinity)
        }

        // Renders the scene and updates the render as needed.
        function run() {

          // Read more about requestAnimationFrame at http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
          requestAnimationFrame(run);
          TWEEN.update();

          // Render the scene.
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
          controls.update();
        }
        
        //document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
        
        function onMouseDown(e) {
          var vectorMouse = new THREE.Vector3( //vector from camera to mouse
            -(window.innerWidth/2-e.clientX)*2/window.innerWidth,
            (window.innerHeight/2-e.clientY)*2/window.innerHeight,
            -1/Math.tan(22.5*Math.PI/180)); //22.5 is half of camera frustum angle 45 degree
          vectorMouse.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
          vectorMouse.normalize();        

          var vectorObject = new THREE.Vector3(); //vector from camera to object
          vectorObject.set(object.x - camera.position.x,
                           object.y - camera.position.y,
                           object.z - camera.position.z);
          vectorObject.normalize();
          if (vectorMouse.angleTo(vectorObject)*180/Math.PI < 1) {
            //mouse's position is near object's position
            console.log("click");
          }
        }
      }
      
      createObject("http://www.amdesigngroup.com/clients/AM_6292_Learning/models/Platform/Platform.json");

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, with the two models I am trying to load above, it tells me to use the ObjectLoader instead.  I have tried just switching to the ObjectLoader, but then I get errors about my GeometryUtils.center and the new Geometry.center() syntax gives me even more fatal errors.  I also get errors that a is undefined and a.center is undefined.  What is causing all these errors, and how can I fix them?

All I can think is that JSONLoader and ObjectLoader must work differently and some of the other code must need to be changed, but I can't find much information online or in the documentation, and any change I make just seems to make things worse.

Thank you so much!!!

NOTE: Sorry for the messy code - I realize it's inefficient, at the moment this is just to get the functionality working.  I will clean it up later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/bH30/javascript-threejs-threejs-objectloader-cannot-read-property-fog-of-undefined):

```js
var loader = new ObjectLoader();
loader.load('scene.js', function(object) {
    scene.add(object); // load the object into your scene here
});
```

The problem was I wasn't getting the object as the function argument, and I wasn't adding the object to the scene.  I was just trying to use the mesh/geometry.  Not sure why that doesn't work for the object loader, but it definitely doesn't.  So, the following code works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rotating Sphere</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <!-- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js -->
    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <!-- Tween.js: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tween.js/ -->
    <script src="js/Tween.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; background-color:#6cdbf5;">
    <div class="canvas-wrapper">
      <canvas id="mycanvas">

      </canvas>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script>

      function createObject(filePath) {
        // Set up the scene, camera, and renderer as global variables.
        var canvas = null,
            scene = null,
            camera = null,
            renderer = null,
            mesh = null,
            mesh2 = null,
            object = null;

        init();
        run();

        // Sets up the scene.
        function init() {

          // Get canvas
          canvas = document.getElementById( "mycanvas" );

          // Create the scene and set the scene size.
          scene = new THREE.Scene();
          var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
              HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

          // Create a renderer and add it to the DOM.
          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, alpha:true, canvas:canvas});
          renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
          document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

          // Create a camera, zoom it out from the model a bit, and add it to the scene.
          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 20000);
          camera.position.set(0,6,0);
          camera.lookAt(scene.position);
          scene.add(camera);

          // Create an event listener that resizes the renderer with the browser window.
          window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
                HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          });

          // Set the background color of the scene to transparent
          //renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);

          // Create a light, set its position, and add it to the scene.
          var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
          light.position.set(0,0,-100);
          scene.add(light);

          // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
          var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
          loader.load( filePath, function(object, materials){
            //var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/textures/ship.jpg')});
            //object.mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(object.geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
            //mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
            object.rotation.x = - (Math.PI / 2);
            object.rotation.y = Math.PI;
            //mesh.position.set(-1.5, 0, 0);
            scene.add(object);
            //object = mesh;
            //animate(mesh);
          });

          // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
          var loader2 = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
          loader2.load( "models/Platform/Platform.json", function(object, materials){
            //var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x55B663});
            //mesh2 = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
            //mesh2.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
            object.rotation.x = - (Math.PI / 2);
            object.rotation.y = Math.PI;
            object.scale.set(.025, .025, .025);
            object.position.set(0, 1, .4);
            scene.add(object);

            //animate(mesh2);
          });

          // Add OrbitControls so that we can pan around with the mouse.
          controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        }
        
        /* rotate mesh */
        function animate(mesh) {
          var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.rotation)
            .to({ z: "-" + Math.PI/2}, 2500) // relative animation
            .onComplete(function() {
                // Check that the full 360 degrees of rotation, 
                // and calculate the remainder of the division to avoid overflow.
                if (Math.abs(mesh.rotation.z)>=2*Math.PI) {
                    mesh.rotation.y = mesh.rotation.z % (2*Math.PI);
                }
            })
            .start();
          tween.repeat(Infinity)
        }

        // Renders the scene and updates the render as needed.
        function run() {

          // Read more about requestAnimationFrame at http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
          requestAnimationFrame(run);
          TWEEN.update();

          // Render the scene.
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
          controls.update();
        }
        
        //document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
        
        function onMouseDown(e) {
          var vectorMouse = new THREE.Vector3( //vector from camera to mouse
            -(window.innerWidth/2-e.clientX)*2/window.innerWidth,
            (window.innerHeight/2-e.clientY)*2/window.innerHeight,
            -1/Math.tan(22.5*Math.PI/180)); //22.5 is half of camera frustum angle 45 degree
          vectorMouse.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
          vectorMouse.normalize();        

          var vectorObject = new THREE.Vector3(); //vector from camera to object
          vectorObject.set(object.x - camera.position.x,
                           object.y - camera.position.y,
                           object.z - camera.position.z);
          vectorObject.normalize();
          if (vectorMouse.angleTo(vectorObject)*180/Math.PI < 1) {
            //mouse's position is near object's position
            console.log("click");
          }
        }
      }
      
      createObject("models/ConstructionManA_2/ConstructionManA_2.json");

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```